# Parse Error When Creating Array CasperJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, xpath, phantomjs, casperjs

I'm trying to scrape multiple attributes on a site. I was going to load them into an array, then load that array into a table on the db on my server.

I tried to create the function `getInfo()` and load each of these XPath attributes into the array (which I may just load into a table if that's what people suggest). I call that function 5 times in the `casper.repeat` step. I am getting a parse error. I don't know what is going wrong here because this is how I set up the array to scrape URLs and added them to an array (which I found in the manual): [Now let’s scrape Google!](http://casperjs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#now-let-s-scrape-google)

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Code:

```
var links = [];
var utils = require('utils');
var casper = require('casper').create();
casper.userAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36');

function getInfo() {
    var info = document.querySelectorAll(fetchText((x(//*[@id="body"]/div[1]/ul[1]/li[3]/span[1]/span[2]/a)))
    + ', ' + fetchText((x(//*[@id="body"]/div[1]/ul[1]/li[2]/h2/text()))
    + ', ' + fetchText((x()))
    + ', ' + fetchText((x(//*[@id="body"]/div[1]/ul[1]/li[4]/ul/li/span[2]/a)))
    + ', ' + fetchText((x(//*[@id="body"]/div[1]/ul[1]/li[2]/h2/span)))
    + ', ' + fetchText((x(//*[@id="body"]/div[1]/ul[1]/li[5]/div[2]/ul/li[5]/span[2]/a)))
    + ', ' + fetchText((x(//*[@id="body"]/div[1]/ul[1]/li[5]/div[2]/ul/li[1]/span[2])))
    + ', ' + fetchText((x(//*[@id="key"]))
    + ', ' + fetchText((x()))
    + ', ' + fetchText((x(//*[@id="body"]/div[1]/ul[1]/li[5]/div[2]/ul/li[2]/span[2])))
    + ', ' + fetchText((x(//*[@id="body"]/div[1]/ul[1]/li[5]/div[2]/ul/li[6]/span[2]/span[2]/a)))
    + ', ' + fetchText((x())));
    return Array.prototype.map.call(info, function());
}


// This was changed.
casper.repeat(5, function() {
    this.thenOpen(bURL + links[i], function() {
        this.wait(3000);
        info = info.concat(this.evaluate(getInfo));

    });
i++;
}).run();
```

Comment: I removed a part of your question, because it has nothing to do with your initial problem. If you can make it clearer, you can later ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems with your code.

#### 1. Parse error

The parse error that you see is this line:

```
return Array.prototype.map.call(info, function());
```

It should be at least

```
return Array.prototype.map.call(info, function(){});
```

#### <strike>2. undefined error</strike>

*Question was edited so that this section doesn't make sense anymore.*

This is probably a typo, but this line:

```
links = links.concat(this.evaluate(getLinks));
```

should probably be

```
links = links.concat(this.evaluate(getInfo));
```

because there is no `getLinks` function in your code.

#### <strike>3. The increment problem</strike>

*Question was edited so that this section doesn't make sense anymore.*

Written like that you will open the same page 5 times with the initial increment, because you increase the increment inside of the `thenOpen` callback. CasperJS is asynchronous in nature and you only schedule steps (like the `thenOpen` calls).

```
casper.repeat(5, function() {
    this.thenOpen(googleSearch + '&start=' + increment, function() { ... });
    increment += 10;
}).run();
```

#### 4. The async/sync problem

Your `wait(3000)` isn't doing anything, because it is an asynchronous step function followed by a synchronous `evaluate` and `concat`. Step functions will be executed at the end of the current step (here `thenOpen`), but synchronous functions are executed immediately. You can use the `then` callback of `wait` to have synchronous functions. All `then*` and all `wait*` functions are asynchronous step functions.

```
this.thenOpen(googleSearch + '&start=' + increment, function() {
    this.wait(3000, function(){
        // aggregate results for the 'BP' search
        links = links.concat(this.evaluate(getLinks));
    });
});
```

#### 5. XPaths are not regular expressions

XPaths expressions are not native to javascript like regular expressions are. There is no XPath object. XPaths are strings so you need to quote them. This

```
x(//*[@id="key"])
```

must be

```
x('//*[@id="key"]')
```

And in the same way `x("")` is not a valid XPath.

It must be quoted, because everything that begins with `//` outside of a string is a comment in javascript. If you do `fetchText(x(//comment))` you get a lot of unclosed parenthesis. That is why XPaths are represented as strings.

#### 6. Page context

Now to the meat of your script. As I understand it, you want to fetch some texts from the page and send those as an array somewhere.

You use `document.querySelectorAll` inside `getInfo` which suggests that `getInfo` is executed inside of the page context (using `evaluate`), because there is no such thing as `document` outside the page context. Since the page context execution is sandboxed, you cannot use most of the CasperJS functions. Only the [`__utils__`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/clientutils.html) is injected into the page context. `fetchText` is not one of them and the same goes for the XPath utility `x` which you have to add to the top of your script:

```
var x = require('casper').selectXPath;
```

The other strange thing is that you want to use the selected text inside `document.querySelectorAll` which makes only sense if the texts where actually CSS selectors which they are probably not since you're scraping google search.

The next thing is that

```
return Array.prototype.map.call(info, function(){});
```

will return an array of `undefined` values.

### Solution:

You don't need the page context for this. You would do this completely outside:

```
function getInfo() {
    var info = [
        casper.fetchText(x('//*[@id="body"]/div[1]/ul[1]/li[3]/span[1]/span[2]/a'))
        , casper.fetchText(x('//*[@id="body"]/div[1]/ul[1]/li[2]/h2/text()'))
        , casper.fetchText(x('//*[@id="body"]/div[1]/ul[1]/li[4]/ul/li/span[2]/a'))
        , casper.fetchText(x('//*[@id="body"]/div[1]/ul[1]/li[2]/h2/span'))
        , casper.fetchText(x('//*[@id="body"]/div[1]/ul[1]/li[5]/div[2]/ul/li[5]/span[2]/a'))
        , casper.fetchText(x('//*[@id="body"]/div[1]/ul[1]/li[5]/div[2]/ul/li[1]/span[2]'))
        , casper.fetchText(x('//*[@id="key"]'))
        , casper.fetchText(x('//*[@id="body"]/div[1]/ul[1]/li[5]/div[2]/ul/li[2]/span[2]'))
        , casper.fetchText(x('//*[@id="body"]/div[1]/ul[1]/li[5]/div[2]/ul/li[6]/span[2]/span[2]/a'))
    ]; // this is your array
    return info;
}

casper.repeat(5, function() {
    this.thenOpen(googleSearch + '&start=' + increment, function() {
        this.wait(3000, function(){
            links = links.concat(getInfo());
        });
    });
    increment += 10;
}).then(function(){
    // do something with `links` here
}).run();
```

Comment: This is extremely helpful. Thank you. However, the function which you removed was not the right one. I replaced it with the right one that was supposed to be in the question ( it is located under `// This was changed.`). I want to go back through each array node and check to make sure the data was stored properly. Also, I added the `+ ',' +` so when I extract the data, I could use this as a means to separate it. Why wouldn't that work? I replaced what you said, but am still receiving a parse error.

Comment: I did not add this as I could not understand where to implement it: `return Array.prototype.map.call(info, function(){});`. Maybe this is the problem? Also, I did not place all my code here. There are some things that I left out as I felt they didn't matter. This may seem why some of the stuff is strange (sorry). Finally, I have `var casper = require('casper').create();`... would `var casper = require('casper').create().selectXPath;` be legal?

Comment: @user3930517 No, that last thing is not ok since you overwrite the casper reference with the XPath utility. The other parse problem is described under number 5 in my answer. Please take your time to go through every point. I have described everything in detail.

Comment: OK, thanks. ...No. I read your entire comment. It was very helpful. I feel you are not understanding me. I am not talking about the XPath not being a regular expression, I am asking how I can separate each XPath inside the array node for future extraction.

Comment: Well, I don't understand what you mean with separating XPath expressions for future extractions. If something begins with `//` it is a comment in javascript. Since all your XPaths begin with a `//`, everything behind it is parsed as comments. This means that you end up with a lot of unclosed parenthesis: `(//comment)` which is why you get a parse error.

Comment: I understand this. What I am referring to is this:

`array = [I,want,to,extract,this,do,you,see]`, then be able to extract the `I,want,to,extract,this`. Maybe I would need to use periods instead so it would look like this: `array = [I.want.to.extract.this,do.you.see]`. Note the `do.you.see` would be the second part of the array which I would be able to extract at a different time. So the former is part 1 and the latter is part 2. Does this make sense?

Comment: does that make sense?

Comment: Sure it does, but it has nothing to do with the syntactical and functional problems in my answer. How you construct your array is entirely up to you. If you still have a problem after fixing everything else, you can ask another question. I won't answer your original question here because it just is too much for one thing.